# Oracle EF Core - No suitable constructor was found for entity type

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have the following Model:

- net6.0
- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.9

```cs
public class Invoice{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Guid CustomerId {get;set;}

    public Invoice(Guid customerId){
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

Now executing a query I get the following error message:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Invoice'

I know, adding an private parameterless constructor would solve this issue, but isn't there any "cleaner" solution than adding this needless constructors to keep the models clean?

*And this Post tells, that it is possible [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)*

Comment: The link says something different. This code doesn't set all properties, it doesn't set the Primary key *at all* so can't be used. The very fact the code sets `customerId` instead of `Id` should be a warning sign

Comment: How does EF Core know how to instantiate your entity? How does it know that it has to pass it some value? It's not how it works, it needs to be able to build te object and then hydrate it, including the primary key property.